# Replacing string with placeholder and replacing them back after a function.

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, placeholder

Given a string and a list of substring that should be replaces as placeholders, e.g.

```
import re
from copy import copy 

phrases = ["'s morgen", "'s-Hertogenbosch", "depository financial institution"]
original_text = "Something, 's morgen, ik 's-Hertogenbosch im das depository financial institution gehen"
```

The first goal is to first replace the substrings from `phrases` in the `original_text` with indexed placeholders, e.g.

```
text = copy(original_text)
backplacement = {}
for i, phrase in enumerate(phrases):
    backplacement["MWEPHRASE{}".format(i)] = phrase.replace(' ', '_')
    text = re.sub(r"{}".format(phrase), "MWEPHRASE{}".format(i), text)
print(text)
```

[out]:

```
Something, MWEPHRASE0, ik MWEPHRASE1 im das MWEPHRASE2 gehen
```

Then there'll be some functions to manipulate the `text` with the placeholders, e.g.

```
cleaned_text = func('Something, MWEPHRASE0, ik MWEPHRASE1 im das MWEPHRASE2 gehen')
print(cleaned_text)
```

that outputs:

```
MWEPHRASE0 ik MWEPHRASE1 MWEPHRASE2
```

the last step is to do the replacement we did in a backwards manner and put back the original phrases, i.e.

```
' '.join([backplacement[tok] if tok in backplacement else tok for tok in clean_text.split()])
```

[out]:

```
"'s_morgen ik 's-Hertogenbosch depository_financial_institution"
```

The questions are:

1. If the list of substrngs in `phrases` is huge, the time to do the 1st replacement and the last backplacement would take very long.

**Is there a way to do the replacement/backplacement with a regex?**

2. using the `re.sub(r"{}".format(phrase), "MWEPHRASE{}".format(i), text)` regex substitution isn't very helpful esp. if there are substrings in the phrases that matches not the full word,

E.g.

```
phrases = ["org", "'s-Hertogenbosch", "depository financial institution"]
original_text = "Something, 's morgen, ik 's-Hertogenbosch im das depository financial institution gehen"
backplacement = {}
text = copy(original_text)
for i, phrase in enumerate(phrases):
    backplacement["MWEPHRASE{}".format(i)] = phrase.replace(' ', '_')
    text = re.sub(r"{}".format(phrase), "MWEPHRASE{}".format(i), text)
print(text)
```

we get an awkward output:

```
Something, 's mMWEPHRASE0en, ik MWEPHRASE1 im das MWEPHRASE2 gehen
```

I've tried using `'\b{}\b'.format(phrase)` but that'll didn't work for the phrases with punctuations, i.e.

```
phrases = ["'s morgen", "'s-Hertogenbosch", "depository financial institution"]
original_text = "Something, 's morgen, ik 's-Hertogenbosch im das depository financial institution gehen"
backplacement = {}
text = copy(original_text)
for i, phrase in enumerate(phrases):
    backplacement["MWEPHRASE{}".format(i)] = phrase.replace(' ', '_')
    text = re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(phrase), "MWEPHRASE{}".format(i), text)
print(text)
```

[out]:

```
Something, 's morgen, ik 's-Hertogenbosch im das MWEPHRASE2 gehen
```

**Is there some where to denote the word boundary for the phrases in the `re.sub` regex pattern?**

Comment: In your desired output, all strings that do not occur in `phrases` are removed, except for `ik`. Why is that?

Comment: You're doing this the hard way. `Then there'll be some functions to manipulate the text with the placeholders`. So, you have a function to work on the text after adding the placeholders.  And that function must do a split on whitespace or something. So, now you have an array where you manipulate all the elements except the placeholders, then you want to join the array into a string, then substitute the placeholders back using the real words. Is that correct ?

Comment: Single pass, I would match all the words using a regex and put them into two dimension array ( or list). Dimension 0 is the string part, dimension 1 is a flag. When you match a non-phrase string part, the flag is 0, when it is a phrase word, the flag is 1. You can then iterate the array and ignore the ones where the flag is 1. Add, delete, re-arrange elements as needed. Then join them back together. The regex is simple `((?:(?!phrase1|phrase2|phrase3)[\S\s])+)|(phrase1|phrase2|phrase3)`. Where, capture group 1 is a non-phrase string part, capture group 2 is a phrase.

Comment: This seem to be one alternative: https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext

Comment: As for the word boundary, you must be looking for `r"(?<!\w){}(?!\w)".format(phrase)`. Since some of your keywords start with a non-word chars, you cannot use `\b`. Could you please provide some more logic that you need to implement? It looks like you might need to pass a callback/lambda as the second argument to `re.sub` to replace each match just once.

Comment: Have you tried my approach? Or do you want to switch to FlashText now?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using re.sub you can split it!

```
def do_something_with_str(string):
    # do something with string here.
    # for example let's wrap the string with "@" symbol if it's not empty
    return f"@{string}" if string else string


def get_replaced_list(string, words):
    result = [(string, True), ]

    # we take each word we want to replace
    for w in words:

        new_result = []

        # Getting each word in old result
        for r in result:

            # Now we split every string in results using our word.
            split_list = list((x, True) for x in r[0].split(w)) if r[1] else list([r, ])

            # If we replace successfully - add all the strings
            if len(split_list) > 1:

                # This one would be for [text, replaced, text, replaced...]
                sub_result = []
                ws = [(w, False), ] * (len(split_list) - 1)
                for x, replaced in zip(split_list, ws):
                    sub_result.append(x)
                    sub_result.append(replaced)
                sub_result.append(split_list[-1])

                # Add to new result
                new_result.extend(sub_result)

            # If not - just add it to results
            else:
                new_result.extend(split_list)
        result = new_result
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    initial_string = 'acbbcbbcacbbcbbcacbbcbbca'
    words_to_replace = ('a', 'c')
    replaced_list = get_replaced_list(initial_string, words_to_replace)
    modified_list = [(do_something_with_str(x[0]), True) if x[1] else x for x in replaced_list]
    final_string = ''.join([x[0] for x in modified_list])
```

Here's variables values of the example above:

```
initial_string = 'acbbcbbcacbbcbbcacbbcbbca'
words_to_replace = ('a', 'c')
replaced_list = [('', True), ('a', False), ('', True), ('c', False), ('bb', True), ('c', False), ('bb', True), ('c', False), ('', True), ('a', False), ('', True), ('c', False), ('bb', True), ('c', False), ('bb', True), ('c', False), ('', True), ('a', False), ('', True), ('c', False), ('bb', True), ('c', False), ('bb', True), ('c', False), ('', True), ('a', False), ('', True)]
modified_list = [('', True), ('a', False), ('', True), ('c', False), ('@bb', True), ('c', False), ('@bb', True), ('c', False), ('', True), ('a', False), ('', True), ('c', False), ('@bb', True), ('c', False), ('@bb', True), ('c', False), ('', True), ('a', False), ('', True), ('c', False), ('@bb', True), ('c', False), ('@bb', True), ('c', False), ('', True), ('a', False), ('', True)]
final_string = 'ac@bbc@bbcac@bbc@bbcac@bbc@bbca'
```

As you can see the lists contain tuples. They contain two values - `some string` and `boolean`, representing whether it's a text or replaced value (`True` when text).
After you get replaced list, you can modify it as in the example, checking if it's text value (`if x[1] == True`).
Hope that helps!

*P.S. String formatting like* `f"some string here {some_variable_here}"` *requires Python 3.6*

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two keys to using regular expressions for this task:

1. Use custom boundaries, capture them, and substitute them back, along with the phrase.
2. Use a function to process the substitution matches, in both directions.

Below is an implementation that uses this approach. I tweaked your text slightly to repeat one of the phrases.

```
import re
from copy import copy 

original_text = "Something, 's morgen, ik 's-Hertogenbosch im das depository financial institution gehen 's morgen"
text = copy(original_text)

#
# The phrases of interest
#
phrases = ["'s morgen", "'s-Hertogenbosch", "depository financial institution"]

#
# Create the mapping dictionaries
#
phrase_to_mwe = {}
mwe_to_phrase = {}

#
# Build the mappings
#
for i, phrase in enumerate(phrases):

    mwephrase                = "MWEPHRASE{}".format(i)
    mwe_to_phrase[mwephrase] = phrase.replace(' ', '_')
    phrase_to_mwe[phrase]    = mwephrase

#
# Regex match handlers
#
def handle_forward(match):

    b1     = match.group(1)
    phrase = match.group(2)
    b2     = match.group(3)

    return b1 + phrase_to_mwe[phrase] + b2


def handle_backward(match):

    return mwe_to_phrase[match.group(1)]

#
# The forward regex will look like:
#
#    (^|[ ])('s morgen|'s-Hertogenbosch|depository financial institution)([, ]|$)
# 
# which captures three components:
#
#    (1) Front boundary
#    (2) Phrase
#    (3) Back boundary
#
# Anchors allow matching at the beginning and end of the text. Addtional boundary characters can be
# added as necessary, e.g. to allow semicolons after a phrase, we could update the back boundary to:
#
#    ([,; ]|$)
#
regex_forward  = re.compile(r'(^|[ ])(' + '|'.join(phrases) + r')([, ]|$)')
regex_backward = re.compile(r'(MWEPHRASE\d+)')

#
# Pretend we cleaned the text in the middle
#
cleaned = 'MWEPHRASE0 ik MWEPHRASE1 MWEPHRASE2 MWEPHRASE0'

#
# Do the translations
#
text1 = regex_forward .sub(handle_forward,  text)
text2 = regex_backward.sub(handle_backward, cleaned)

print('original: {}'.format(original_text))
print('text1   : {}'.format(text1))
print('text2   : {}'.format(text2))
```

Running this generates:

```
original: Something, 's morgen, ik 's-Hertogenbosch im das depository financial institution gehen 's morgen
text1   : Something, MWEPHRASE0, ik MWEPHRASE1 im das MWEPHRASE2 gehen MWEPHRASE0
text2   : 's_morgen ik 's-Hertogenbosch depository_financial_institution 's_morgen
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a strategy you could use:

```
phrases = ["'s morgen", "'s-Hertogenbosch", "depository financial institution"]
original_text = "Something, 's morgen, ik 's-Hertogenbosch im das depository financial institution gehen"

# need this module for the reduce function
import functools as fn

#convert phrases into a dictionary of numbered placeholders (tokens)
tokens = { kw:"MWEPHRASE%s"%i for i,kw in enumerate(phrases) }

#replace embedded phrases with their respective token
tokenized = fn.reduce(lambda s,kw: tokens[kw].join(s.split(kw)), phrases, original_text)

#Apply text cleaning logic on the tokenized text 
#This assumes the placeholders are left untouched, 
#although it's ok to move them around)
cleaned_text = cleanUpfunction(tokenized)

#reverse the token dictionary (to map original phrases to numbered placeholders)
unTokens = {v:k for k,v in tokens.items() }

#rebuild phrases with original text associated to each token (placeholder)
final_text = fn.reduce(lambda s,kw: unTokens[kw].join(s.split(kw)), phrases, cleaned_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "multi-string search" or "multi-pattern search". The more common solutions are Aho-Corasick and Rabin-Karp algorithms. If you want to impement it yourself, go with Rabin-Karp, since its easier to grasp. Otherwise, you'll find some libraries. Here's a solution with the library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py_aho_corasick.

Let

```
phrases = ["'s morgen", "'s-Hertogenbosch", "depository financial institution"]
original_text = "Something, 's morgen, ik 's-Hertogenbosch im das depository financial institution gehen"
```

And, for testing purposes:

```
def clean(text):
    """A simple stub"""
    assert text == 'Something, MWEPHRASE0, ik MWEPHRASE1 im das MWEPHRASE2 gehen'
    return "MWEPHRASE0 ik MWEPHRASE1 MWEPHRASE2"
```

Now, you have to define two automatons, one for the outward journey, and the other for the return. An automaton is defined by a list of (key,value):

```
fore_automaton = py_aho_corasick.Automaton([(phrase,"MWEPHRASE{}".format(i)) for i, phrase in enumerate(phrases)])
back_automaton = py_aho_corasick.Automaton([("MWEPHRASE{}".format(i), phrase.replace(' ','_')) for i, phrase in enumerate(phrases)])
```

The automaton will scan the text and return a list of matches. A match is a triplet (position, key, value). With a little work on matches, you'll be able to replace keys by values:

```
def process(automaton, text):
    """Returns a new text, with keys of the automaton replaced by values"""
    matches = automaton.get_keywords_found(text.lower()) # text.lower() because auomaton of py_aho_corasick uses lowercase for keys
    bk_value_eks = [(i,v,i+len(k)) for i,k,v in matches] # (begin of key, value, end of key)
    chunks = [bk_value_ek1[1]+text[bk_value_ek1[2]:bk_value_ek2[0]] for bk_value_ek1,bk_value_ek2 in zip([(-1,"",0)]+bk_value_eks, bk_value_eks+[(len(text),"",-1)] if bk_value_ek1[2] <= bk_value_ek2[0]] # see below
    return "".join(chunks)
```

A brief explanation on `chunks = [bk_value_ek1[1]+text[bk_value_ek1[2]:bk_value_ek2[0]] for bk_value_ek1,bk_value_ek2 in zip([(-1,"",0)]+bk_value_eks, bk_value_eks+[(len(text),"",-1)] if bk_value_ek1[2] <= bk_value_ek2[0]]`.
I zip matches with itself almost as usual : `zip(arr, arr[1:])` will output `(arr[0], arr[1)), (arr[1], arr[2]), ...` to consider every match with its sucessor. Here I placed two sentinels
to handle the begin and the end of matches.

- For the normal case, I just output the value (=`bk_value_ek1[1]`) and the text between the end of the key and the begin of the next key (`text[bk_value_ek1[2]:bk_value_ek2[0]`).
- The begin sentinel has an empty value, and its key ends at position 0, thus the first chunk will be "" + text[0:begin of key1], that is the text before the first key.
- Similarly, the end sentinel has also an empty value and its key begins at the end of the text, thus the last chunk will be : value of the last match + text[end of the last key:len(text)].

*What happens when keys overlap? Take an example: `text="abcdef"`, `phrases={"bcd":"1", "cde":"2"}`. You have two matches: `(1, "bcd", "1")` and `(2, "cde", "3")`.
Let's go: `bk_value_eks = [(1, "1", 4), (2, "2", 5)]`. Thus, without `if bk_value_ek1[2] <= bk_value_ek2[0]`, the text will be replaced by `text[:1]+"1"+text[4:2]+"2"+text[5:]`,
that is `"a"+"1"+""+"2"+"f"` = `"a12f"` instead of `"a1ef"` (ignore the second match)...*

Now, take a look a the result:

```
print(process(back_automaton, clean(process(fore_automaton, original_text))))
# "'s_morgen ik 's-Hertogenbosch depository_financial_institution"
```

You don't have to define a new `process` function for the return, just give it the `back_automaton` and it will do the job.